# Login em site externo (prefeitura curitiba)

Tags: php, xml

Preciso puxar de um site da prefeitura se determinada empresa emitiu notas fiscais.

Não tem problema se o usuário precisar inserir os captchas manualmente.

O link é esse:
https://isscuritiba.curitiba.pr.gov.br/iss/

> Não quero algo pronto, eu quero saber o que exatamente eu preciso estudar pra conseguir fazer isso, pois
>   não consigo encontrar como esse site passa os parâmetros para o
>   servidor pra que eu possa simular que o PHP esteja navegando por ele.

Comment: Já tentou usar cURL simulando agent?

Comment: O problema não está em si no que fazer, e sim em que eu não consigo encontrar como esse site efetua suas requisições pra que eu possa simular os envios, mas não tentei isso, até vi um exemplo, mas não consegui aplicar, tem alguma fonte de informação sobre isso ?

Comment: Pelo que vi aqui no código fonte do site, quando é clicado no botão "Entrar" é chamada a função "__doPostBack" que por sua vez pega um formulário com campos do tipo "hidden" e da "submit" chamando a própria pagina, "default.aspx". Então o processamento ocorre dentro da própria pagina, esses campos hidden que falei, tem um deles, que é algum tipo de verificador já que cada atualizada na página o valor é trocado, ou seja, você precisa dele caso queira fazer o login.

Comment: Você precisará dos campos tipo hidden da pagina do form 'frmLogin' e conseguir através de file_get_contents ou cURL  o valor do campo PFZ__VIEW__ID varrendo o HTML antes da tentativa de login

Comment: Encontrei esse forum oficial de suporte à desenvolvedores: http://pilotoisscuritiba.curitiba.pr.gov.br/forum_boanota/ talvez você encontre uma resposta lá.

Comment: @lucasvscn nossa, não tinha achado esse fórum, provavelmente alguém deve ter tentado isso antes, vou dar uma pesquisada nos tópicos.

Comment: @BrunoFolle consegui passasr os valores de login para a página, porém ta complicado de fazer o servidor aceitar esse login externo, segunda-feira vou ligar na prefeitura ver se eles oferecem suporte ao desenvolvedor, to achando que tem algum tipo de segurança dentro desse site que bloqueia esse tipo de acesso externo via cURL ou tentando carregar e mandar de outra localização os parâmetros, mas assim que eu conseguir(se for possível) eu coloco aqui como foi feito .